# Equivalence of two equations about power-law distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, equivalence-relations

I have a problem with Power-law distribution. In some sources I found that we can define this class of distribution by probability function:
$$ p(x) = k \cdot x^{-\alpha}, $$ where $\alpha>1$ and k is constant.

On wikipedia I found another definition:
$$ P(X>x) \sim L(x) \cdot x^{-\alpha+1}, $$

where $\alpha >0$ and $L(x)$ is slowly varying function

I would like to show in formal way that these definitions are equivalent.

Comment: I am not sure that they are exactly equivalent (and I think you need $\alpha >1$ in the first definition). If you then integrate $p(t)$ form $x$ to $\infty$ you get $P(X>x)=K \cdot x^{-\alpha+1}$

Comment: Your definition 2) looks like a generalisation, with $L(x)$ almost constant instead of K constant.

Comment: I correct first definition (it should be $\alpha>1$ as you read) and second one (it should be $\alpha>0$)